# Upgraded DD4T app to Web 8.5, multiple Caching Providers configured

Tags: web8.5, dd4t-2, dd4t-java, cil

I'm getting the following exception from the CIL in my DD4T 2 Java project that has been upgraded to Web 8.5

> Could not create CONTENT service client. Error:Unable to load content
>   service url!

Digging into the logs I found the exception to be:

> 2017-05-19 15:15:27,965 WARN  BaseClientConfigurationLoader - Unable
>   to resolve ContentServiceCapability using DiscoveryService:
>   http://stg-discovery:8082/discovery.svc.
>   javax.cache.CacheException: Multiple CachingProviders have been
>   configured when only a single CachingProvider is expected     at
>   javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:376)
>   ~[cache-api-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:351)
>   ~[cache-api-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   javax.cache.Caching.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:142)
>   ~[cache-api-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.sdl.web.client.cache.GeneralCacheProvider.getCacheManager(GeneralCacheProvider.java:138)
>   ~[discovery-client-lightweight-8.5.0-1014.jar:8.5.0-1014]

I'm not sure where these Caching providers are configured.

I've tried adding a few things to my application.properties to hint using the EhCache provider.

Is something in DD4T 2 conflicting with the CIL here? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Edit: I've tried setting the DD4T cache provider to the NoCacheProvider but it's not helped.

Edit: Seems like this is caused by 2 versions of Ehcache. Still trying to figure out how to fix the dependencies to work together.

Comment: I think this is caused by Web 8.5 having moved to ehcache-3.1.3, which has the jcache implementation inside it, whereas in previous versions, you needed to have ehcache-2.x + jcache-1.0.1.jar. If you remove jcache-1.0.1 it should work.

Comment: Hi Rai, that looked like it was going to work but it seems like the org.dd4t.core.providers.EHCacheProvider class has a hard dependency on the EH Cache 2.0 namespace. I tried the NoCacheProvider but it was broken in 2.0.10. I've now got my own NoCacheProvider version and it does work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok - seen the issue come in. I'll have a look later in the week.

Comment: It looks like it's fixed in your refactoring of the caching recently.